# A newer gas hot water heater keeps getting colder. Where is the first place to look?

Tags: water-heater, hot-water

We had a new hot water heater installed 1-2 years ago. It worked great up until about 2 weeks ago, where we all noticed that it no longer was heating to the same temperature. I can continue to crank the heat adjustment up, but that makes me nervous that I'll end up burning my children if it suddenly snaps back. What is the best thing to do to start fixing this?

Comment: Test the heating elements with a voltage meter to see if both are working. I assume it is electric?  Probably one element is not working which could be a bad element or a bad thermostat

Comment: For a start figure out what type of heater it is, then determine if it's heat-making part or the thermostat that is misbehaving,

Comment: @Kris - Sorry, I meant to put it in there, but it is a gas heater, not electric. I've edited the question.

Comment: Have you tried flushing the heater using the drain valve at the bottom? Also, do you have any other gas appliances?

Comment: Is it cooler on all the faucets?

Comment: @EdBeal - Yes, all faucets are coming out cooler, but it is still working. Just not getting hot enough

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - Yes, our furnace is also gas and does not seem to be having issues. I have not flushed it yet, but as I mentioned, it's only a couple years old. Can deposits cause this issue this fast?

Comment: don't you want to know the `last place to look` instead? ... that is always where you find what you are looking for

Comment: Indeed, it was the last place anyone wants to look (under the slab ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It ends up it was not directly the hot water heater. We have a leak in a hot water line that goes down into the foundation of our basement which is even worse. I thought I'd come back and update in case someone sees this in the future. Thank you to all who answered.

Comment: Ouch - those are expensive. Had a hot water leak in a rental where we paid the utilities once...

Comment: @Encerwal Yeah, the water bill is going to be through the roof next quarter. The quote from a plumber was crazy high too and it was best case without ripping up the concrete ($2700). I just ordered an endoscope to see if I can find where the pipes come up. The bathroom in the basement is only 6 feet from the utility room through two walls. If I can find the other side of the pipe, I should be able to cap the end ends going through the ground and run a new pipe instead. Here's hoping!

Comment: That, combined with the incoming water temperature in the winter: it didn't stand a chance.

Answer (score 3):

Flush it using the drain valve. Hard water deposits will settle out on the bottom, and impair the transfer of heat from the flame to the water.

If you are depending on the water heater thermostat to prevent scalding your children, you're not abnormal, but you're doing it wrong.

Use a tempering valve between the water heater and your hot water system. That way you can have the water heater set hot enough to [kill unpleasant bacteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legionella), and also have water that does not scald anyone.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the hot water. I did just flush it today and got a nice bit of buildup out, but the overall functionality and lukewarmness of the water did not seem to improve.